# Traversing down Bootstrap DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML, first:

```
<div id="master-template" class="row" style="height: 600px;">

   <!-- Left Side -->
   <div class="col-lg-6" style="height: 100%;">

       <div class="row"  style="height: 50%;" >

           <div class="region col-lg-12" data-div="1">

           </div>

       </div>

       <div class="row" style="height: 50%;">

           <div class="region col-lg-12" data-div="2">

           </div>

       </div>

   </div>

   <!-- Right Side -->
   <div class="region col-lg-6" style="height: 100%;" data-div="3">

   </div>

 </div>
```

And my `jQuery`:

```
$("#master-template").find('.region').click(function() {
    alert("click");
});
```

So, I only get the alert when I click on the "Right Side".  Because it is a direct descendant.  The others do not register; almost as if the `.row` is blocking it.  Is there a way I can (with either one or two) `click` functions in jQuery register clicks for all `div`'s with `.region`?  children, grandchildren, etc?

Comment: Do all those `.region` elements exist when you bind the handler? If not, just put the handler directly on `master-template` and use `.on` with a delegate selector. `$("#master-template").on("click", ".region", func...)`

Comment: In that case, your code works fine as long as there's something to click. http://jsfiddle.net/wbu720y7/

Comment: @squint that works just like the OPs description.\

Comment: @KevinBoucher: What does?

Comment: @squint clicking the first two does nothing. I believe the answer is below.

Comment: @KevinBoucher: That was only a solution if the elements were not present when the page loads. We don't have the CSS for these elements, so I don't know if it's an issue of the div being collapsed, or not, hence the jsFiddle demo.

Comment: There is no additional CSS outside of `bootstrap` stuff.

Comment: My point was, you said it worked fine and provided a Fiddle. I'm saying that  Fiddle demonstrates the described problem.

Comment: @KevinBoucher The fiddle does exactly what the script is supposed to do...Maybe explain what you are trying to achieve. Maybe you are looking for something like this `$( "div" ).has( ".region" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because *Right Side* is the only `.region` DIV that has any dimension. (By virtue of `height:100%`).

The other two `.region`s are not being *clicked* because they have no dimension (`height` is *0*)